# Baidu Push Notifications in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, baidu

How to retrieve data from key value pair in Baidu push notifications?

which method is called in `PushMessageReceiver` in baidu like `onHandleIntent()` method in `GcmListenerService` in Google push notifications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in baidu the payload is only delivered to the app's receiver only if the message sent from the baidu console/your API is of type Transparent.
You can override onMessage() to get the payload.

Comment: Am using cordova plugin .. am able to receive message in onNotficationArrived event .. This does not have notification details like whether it is coldstart or background state etc... After few research it seems it comes in onMesssage event. How to trigger this event ? Also as you mentioned message type is  Transparent . What exactly is this and where to configure ? Our Notifications are triggered through API .. Azure